# Find Apache memory leaks in operational web-instance

Tags: apache, debugging, memory-leaks

I'm running a heavily used apache server, which hosts webpage, downloads, svn (using DAV svn) and a Trac instance (using mod_python). Mod_deflate is used to save bandwith for users. The server has a serious memory issue. Usually after 24 hours it takes 2 GB more memory than after a fresh start.

I installed a monitor of the garbage collector state in the trac system, which indicates, that python (and thus trac) does not have a memory leak.

Now I'm a bit lost how to proceed to find the issue.

Any help and suggestions where to look and how to find the cause of that memory increase would be helpful. LogLevel is set to debug, but I don't find anything helpful in the log.

The system uses Apache 2.2.22 worker-mpm.

Currently apache is restarted every 24 hours as workaround. If I set a value for `MaxRequestsPerChild` (e.g. 500), it seems to gets unresponsive very soon (hanging connections?).

Comment: How do you measure the used memory? Anyway if you log the process ids to the logfile (%P), and check the size of processes, then maybe you can find which request made the given process too big. (if there is any specific request.)

Comment: Memory is measured simply by using "ps" and a look at the process memory, thus no caching effects should be involved, but only real memory. Logging the Process ID is an idea, but I doubt it will help, as there are really a lot of requests involved and I doubt I have a chance to break it down from the ID to specific calls.

Comment: I don't really understand your goal? Generally the processes wouldn't take less memory. You have to target somehow the problematic requests, and try to optimise them. I think...

Comment: I agree, but I doubt that the process ID helps to do so. There are too much requests handled by each process. I need something which is more finegrained. Something like valgrind would be fine, but I can't use valgrind on a heavy loaded apache. Something else would be internal apache statistics, but what I found till now was not enough to help track down the problem. I once wrote a software which had a debug mode to output all memory requests and some information about where they occurred (something like an internal valgrind :-). That would be fine.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/369099/how-to-investigate-a-memory-leak-with-apache-and-php you should see this post.Which is similar to your post.